# ASP.NET MVC html page authentication

Tags: asp.net, html, authentication

I have some static (pure html) pages in my MVC application that I need to authenticate, so that not just anybody can look at them. Is there an way to do this without moving all the code to asp files and adding a controller and from there use the Authorize attribute? I would really prefer to not need to do this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those static HTML pages are in a separate folder, You could configure IIS & Windows Folder security using IIS Admin.

You might also want to look at [role based security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000965/how-add-role-based-security-the-files-in-a-folder) , however I'm not sure if that will work for static HTML files (non .aspx).

Comment: Thanks! I looked into role based security, and our solution to block out any user who was not logged in is as follows:

<location path="StaticPages">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

worked like a charm!

Comment: You must be using IIS7 then, since my suspicion is that this would not be possible in IIS6...  Is that true?

Answer (score 3):

I looked into role-based security, and I found that adding

```
<location path="StaticPages">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

to the web.config file worked like a charm! It blocks any users who are not logged into the website.